# How to execute an exe in an iPad application?

Tags: xcode, ipad

I want to add a file to my iPad application and call it, it take parameters like `-h`.

Any suggestion how to do that?

Comment: Where did you get the "exe" from?

Comment: I didn't understand 1, it's an ipad application as the tags mentioned   , the exe is mac exe file , I don't have any code because I don't know how to implement that

Comment: Traditionally 'exe' means Windows Executable, because the filename is '.exe'. Mac executables are just binary files with execute permissions, but more often Application bundles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that's even possible. To begin with, the iPad has an ARM processor while Macs generally have Intel or PowerPC processors, so the processor architectures are incompatible.

Not to mention that the operating systems probably aren't fully compatible either.

It would likely take an entire virtual machine to run that exe, and that's just not feasible. Find the source code for it and compile it into something that can run on the iPad, or just rewrite the functionality of the exe.

Comment: it's a compiled.mach-o executable  file

Comment: Compiled mach-o for **what**?   There are at 3 OSes and about a dozen CPU architectures that can run various forms of `mach-o` files.  Not that it matters;  even if you had the appropriate mach-o for the right system and architecture, you can't launch it.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt this is a good idea, but you may be able to `fork` and `exec` your way into having a separate process.  However, if you plan to make an iOS app, this probably won't fly with Apple.  So, it would probably be easier to simply create a static library and link the result into your main application.

Beyond that, it's just a matter of trying and seeing if it works.

Comment: the file wil be embeded at my main application (it much like the batch file in windows ) I will call it by passing parameter , is this ablicable

Comment: it's compiled.mach-o executable file

Answer (score 2):

You can't `fork/exec`, use `NSTask` or otherwise launch processes from within an application in an iOS app.

So, no, there is no way to do what you are asking (assuming that any of us understand what you are asking -- it is a very poorly worded question).

To make it clear:

### You cannot launch an external process in an iOS app to be distributed via the App Store.

Comment: the file wil be embeded at my main application (it much like the batch file in windows ) I will call it by passing parameter , is this ablicable

Comment: it's compiled.mach-o executable file

Comment: Also -- you really need to learn to ask questions properly.  You keep repeating "it's a compiled mach-o executable file" without answering what kind and for what architecture.  Not that it actually matters, because you can't launch an external process no matter what it is.

Comment: Sort of figured that'd be the case.  Also wish I'd remembered NSTask, not that it would've made a difference.

Comment: you can download the file I want to add and call from here 

http://www.zshare.net/download/86883136591de4b6/

u could test using -h as parameter